# Get row date entered for sql server table without datestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a sql server 2012 table with a bunch of columns - none of these columns are a date/time stamp. Is there any way to get the date the rows were entered? Is there a hidden sys column somewhere that I can latch onto, just as a temporary measure?

Comment: No, there are no such hidden columns in SQL Server.  If you want a column that does that you have to make it yourself.

Comment: The transaction logs should show you when rows are inserted, but they can be massive, don't live forever and aren't easy to search through.

Comment: There is no hidden native SQL column. But, maybe, previous programmer put some triggers to audit data to other table. Cross your fingers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hidden sys column, but if you are using transaction logging you can try a log reader to view all the INSERT statements on the table.

Answer (score -1):

To be able to use the date information.  You should add a new column such as time_stamp and define an after insert trigger.   Good luck.